# Check of specific radio button is checked and it doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I want to show the ptext when radio button has checked and hide when another radio button is active
but does not work

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="postageyes" name="type" value="Paint" type="radio">Paint
    <br>
    <input id="postageno" name="type" value="Sculpture" type="radio">Sculpture
    <br>
    <input id="postageno" name="type" value="calligraphy" type="radio">calligraphy
    <br>
    <input id="stext" name="type" value="type" type="text"><br>
    <input id="ctext" name="type" value="type" type="text"><br>
    <input id="ptext" name="type" value="type" type="text">
    <script type="text/javascript">

      $('input:radio[name="postage"]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Paint') {
          $("#ptext").show();
        } else {
          $("#ptext").hide();
        }
      });

    </script>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have two `input`s with same `id`.

Comment: You have no such name attribute with the value of `postage`...

Comment: There's no `input` with `name="postage"`

Comment: `id` should be unique in same document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two **major** issues:

- The value of `id` should be unique.
- There's no `input` with `name` as `postage`.
- **Extra:** Better to hide the `ptext` when loading the page.

Change the `name` to `postage`:

```
<input id="postageyes" name="postage" value="Paint" type="radio">Paint
<br>
<input id="postageno1" name="postage" value="Sculpture" type="radio">Sculpture
<br>
<input id="postageno2" name="postage" value="calligraphy" type="radio">calligraphy
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="postageyes" name="postage" value="Paint" type="radio">Paint
<br>
<input id="postageno1" name="postage" value="Sculpture" type="radio">Sculpture
<br>
<input id="postageno2" name="postage" value="calligraphy" type="radio">calligraphy
<br>
<input id="stext" name="type" value="type" type="text"><br>
<input id="ctext" name="type" value="type" type="text"><br>
<input id="ptext" name="type" value="type" type="text">
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#ptext").hide();
  $('input:radio[name="postage"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Paint') {
      $("#ptext").show();
    } else {
      $("#ptext").hide();
    }
  });

</script>
```

Also, it is better to hide it when you load the document. See the above example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass wrong radio button name in `jQuery`, Could you please check below code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('input:radio[name="type"]').change(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == 'Paint') {
        $("#ptext").show();
      } else {
        $("#ptext").hide();
      }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: This actually screws up the whole concept. The `type` is being used by the text inputs.

Comment: Would you wanna change your answer?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML** - The fix was only in the name attribute, becase in your html says "Type" instead of "postage"

```
<input id="postageyes" name="postage" value="Paint" type="radio">Paint
    <br>
    <input id="postageno" name="postage" value="Sculpture" type="radio">Sculpture
    <br>
    <input id="postageno" name="postage" value="calligraphy" type="radio">calligraphy
    <br>
    <input id="stext" name="type" value="type" type="text"><br>
    <input id="ctext" name="type" value="type" type="text"><br>
    <input id="ptext" name="type" value="type" type="text" style="display:none">
```

**Javascript** - The javascript if working I only will give you a recommendation and is, use the document ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input:radio[name="postage"]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Paint') {
          $("#ptext").show();
        } else {
          $("#ptext").hide();
        }
      });

});
```